# Planning calendar default one month view on mobile

Tags: calendar, sapui5, sap-fiori

Currently, I am developing an app in which users should be able to pick a date from the calendar. It works pretty much ok on desktop and also on mobile phone. 
My problem is that the 'One Month' view is not reachable from mobile phones. What I need is to be able to have a similar view to the one shown below from my mobile phone.

I have already tried to PlanningCalendarView with `intervalType="Month"` but it just made it worse cause it shows the same appointments associated.

[image: One Month Default view on Size=M]

Comment: I try to understand the issue:
You say, the “One Month”-view is not reachable on the mobile phone.
Do you see the Pull-Down menu, where you can select the time period  (Hours, Days, Months, 1 Week, 1 Month)?

I have just tested 
[Sample: simple Planning Calendar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/preview) 
on a S7 mobile phone (although in German language) and it seems to work ok.

Comment: I have Iphone 6 and in the dropdown menu it doesn't have One Month section although in the simnulation in web ide, I am able to see that option for Iphone 6 devices.

Comment: Does this [sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/preview) work on your Iphone 6?
Do you see the “1 Month” section if you turn the mobile phone into portrait mode ?
The “1 Month” section is at the very bottom of the dropdown menu and you can swipe the menu in the upward direction to see it.

Comment: It is pretty weird cause I am able to see it. Is there any option that we can use that 1 month option under custom PlanningCalendarView? I mean before I was asking this question I was using the standard view options which include 1 month. But after that I have changed the code with custom views and now I have 2 intervalType options for "Day" and "Week" on mobile phone. But the "Month" option is for combining multiple months and there is no such a thing for "1 Month" type. Pleasee help me out on this! Thanks

Comment: When you say “custom PlanningCalendarView”, are you referring to your own coding, developed by yourself?
Maybe it would be helpful if you could build a working sample of your code in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ .
This way we could debug the issue.

In this sample https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/preview
you can also look at the corresponding source code.

Answer (score 1):

The “1 Month” option is not supported as intervalType for PlanningCalendarView.

But you can combine both your custom views ("Day" , "Week") and the already built in view for “1 Month” 
by using the “builtInViews” property from PlanningCalendar.
Something like:

```
...
<PlanningCalendar
    id="PC1"
    startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"
    rows="{path: '/people'}"

    builtInViews="One Month"
...
<views>
    <PlanningCalendarView

...
```

Please see also this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aqv81MIw1o0eB4u00qSY?p=preview).